# Jquery css image overflow hidden left transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I'm trying to combine my css and Jquery script in order to show an image which is at the beginning hidden and show it by doing a left transition.

I know that I can do it with pure Jquery by using animate left, but for my need, I must use css and add the class.

**My html:**

```
<div id="wapperimg">
<img class="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" />
</div>
<button id="ok">ok</button>
```

**my css :**

```
#wrapperimg {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    left: -100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: 1s;
}
.shown .slide {
transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ok').click(function() {
$("#wappering .slide").addClass('shown');
   });
});
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?
Regards,
Jarod

Comment: I think you need `.shown.slide`, without the space.

Comment: Hi John, I also tried .shown.slide, there is no effect when I click on OK button

Comment: That's one, among other bugs. `$("#wappering .slide")` has a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in

```
$("#wappering .slide")
```

Should be

```
$("#wapperimg .slide")
```

And also you should remove `.slide` from `.shown .slide`:

```
.shown {
transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/43WxB/

Comment: @user979974, mark my answer as the proper solution to your question.

Answer (score -1):

looks like your adding a class of shown to the image which has the class of slide...

Surely your CSS should look like this

```
.slide.shown  {
transition: all ease 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. I did the modification by putting .slide.shown but there is no effect when I click on OK button.

Comment: you transition property is also incorrect, see my answer, should be transition: all ease 1s; plus your typo... Why -1 for this?

Comment: yes you are right  user1676224. Thx. I will change it by transition: all ease 1s;